# dataset API RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a scalable min max scaler with tensorflow dataset API and map function.

First I loop through my dataset to find the min and max values for all features (3) and then I would like to apply the min/max scaler to the dataset using map function.

Here is my simple code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
b_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b).batch(2)

my_iterator = b_ds.make_one_shot_iterator()

def compute_min_max(i, my_min, my_max):
    new_batch = my_iterator.get_next()
    my_min = tf.minimum(my_min,tf.reduce_min(new_batch, axis=0))
    my_max = tf.maximum(my_max,tf.reduce_max(new_batch, axis=0))
    return [i+1, my_min, my_max]

i = tf.constant(0)
feat_min = tf.Variable([10,10,10],dtype=tf.int64)
feat_max = tf.Variable([0,0,0],dtype=tf.int64)

c = lambda i, min, max: i < 2
b = lambda i, min, max: compute_min_max(i, min, max)
res_i, res_min, res_max = tf.while_loop(c, b, loop_vars=[i, feat_min, feat_max])

def min_max_ds(feat):
    return tf.cast(feat-res_min,dtype=tf.float64)/tf.cast(res_max-res_min, dtype=tf.float64)

minmax_scaled_ds = b_ds.map(min_max_ds)

scaled_batch = minmax_scaled_ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run((res_min, res_max, scaled_batch)))
```

When I execute this code I get a

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

My guess is that the min_max_ds function calls back the tf.while_loop statement for every batch or so, but I can't figure how to kind of freeze res_min and res_max so they are used as constant in the min_max_ds function.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can set a higher limit for recursion depth using:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

The default value in python3.X is 1000. A bigger value maybe work.

Comment: If you have tried it yourself then be confident with the writings in your answer.